# how to create a Python global variable whose name is the value of another variable

Tags: python, variables, dynamic, global

Given...

```
myGlobalVariableName = "zorp"
myGlobalVariableValue = "hello"
```

, ...how can I use the values of `myGlobalVariableName` and `myGlobalVariableValue` to create the global variable `"zorp"` and set it to `"hello"`?

The following approach sort-of works, but it's truly horrible:

```
exec( """
global %s
%s = %r   
""" % (
        myGlobalVariableName,
        myGlobalVariableName, myGlobalVariableValue,
    ),
)
```

I think maybe my problem is that I don't know how to address the `__main__` module object's `__dict__` attribute's value.  If I knew how to do that, maybe I could simply say:

```
<main_module_object>.__dict__[ myGlobalVariableName] = myGlobalVariableValue
```

Anyway, that's the kind of answer I'm looking for, I think.

Comment: I don't think this is what you need. However, say you managed to create a variable called `zorp`. How would you use it? You would have to have written a program that expected `zorp` to exist and known its name.

Comment: You should not do this. This is clearly XY problem. Probably you want to use a data structure like dict. Elaborate what you actually want to achieve with this

Comment: The "How do I create variable variables?" posting is not helpful, alas, because nowhere does it say how to tweak the namespace of the main module's globals.  That's what I want to do, and again you'll have to trust me that it's a good idea to do it.  Piety and doctrine have their place, but so do exigency and practicality.  Sometimes, we just need to get the job done, even if our operating patches may be suboptimal in one or more ways, including subsequent maintainability.

Comment: @SteveNewcomb: So is `globals()` what you are looking for?

Comment: Turns out: Yes for the CPython implementation I'm using under Debian.  I've encountered many warnings about the use of the dictionary references returned by `globals()` and `locals()`.  Currently, those warnings don't seem to apply.  Bottom line, you can tweak the module's global namespace from anywhere in the code of the module, including in functions, using `globals()[ varname]`.  Even `del globals()[ varname ]` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

globals() allows you to modify the global namespace.

```
myGlobalVariableName = "zorp"
myGlobalVariableValue = "hello"

globals()[myGlobalVariableName] = myGlobalVariableValue

print(zorp)

Output:
hello
```

Comment: Yes, and the best part is that it works inside any function of the module.  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I took away that you're trying to create a new global variable using a previously defined one. You can use the `gloabls()` method in the main python library. For example

```
def set_value():
    global global_var_name
    global_var_name = "global_var_value"

set_value()

global zorp
zorp = globals()["global_var_name"] = "hello"
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `global zorp` does nothing here.

Comment: There is very little reason to use the global keyword here.  The OP is asking how to use variables to create a variable in the global name scope.

Comment: Ah I see, the OP question was a little confusing so makes sense.